# Web cam video feed to an android application

Tags: android, windows

I want to create an android application to display the video feed from a web camera of a laptop.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for this you need to implement UDP socket connection and broadcast streaming video to your android device IP. UDP is the fast way transferring